# Overriding behaviour of sibling components

Tags: reactjs, redux

I've been struggling with the concept of overriding the behaviour of components between sibling components (components that do not have a parent-child relationship).

I have an App component that renders a header and a content component. The header contains a button that will let a user navigate back (not for real in this example). Now I want the content component to override the back button's behaviour, for example if a user is editing a form and I want to pop up a modal.

The reason I want to do this is because I want to (optionally) control navigation from within the content component itself.

I have found this (see snippet) solution, but I feel like it's not the right way to handle this. I would like to have some advice on how to handle this situation.

A few side-notes:

- I'm actually building a react-native app, but in the hope of reaching more people I've simplified it down to a react example. I'm using NavigatorExperimental for navigation.
- I am using redux/redux-form

Any help is appreciated.

```js
class NavigationHeader extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
       <span onClick={this.props.goBack}>Go back!</span>
    );
  }
}

class Content extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.setBackButtonBehaviour(() => console.log("BackButton overridden from Content"));
  }
  
  componentWillUnmount() {
     this.props.resetBackButtonBehaviour();
  }
  
  render() {
    return (<div style={{background: "red"}}>Content</div>); 
  }

}

class Navigator extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
      
    this.state = {
      overrideHeaderBackButtonBehaviour: null
    }
  }
  
  setBackButtonBehaviour(func) {
      this.setState({overrideHeaderBackButtonBehaviour: func});
  }
    
  resetBackButtonBehaviour() {
       this.setState({overrideHeaderBackButtonBehaviour: null});
  }
    
  defaultBackButtonBehaviour() {
    console.log("Default back-button behaviour");
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <NavigationHeader goBack={this.state.overrideHeaderBackButtonBehaviour || this.defaultBackButtonBehaviour} />
        <Content
          setBackButtonBehaviour={this.setBackButtonBehaviour.bind(this)} 
          resetBackButtonBehaviour={this.resetBackButtonBehaviour.bind(this)}
    />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Navigator />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
</div>
```

Comment: What's exactly your question? Have you got any problem with that code? I think It's correctly written and It´ll work fine.
You should add a constructor to Header class like you did in App class in order to receive props.
But i think it is good

Comment: I want to know whether this is a bad practice or not, since it's not really the "react-way" of doing things. I know it's working fine. I just wonder what the best way is to handle this use-case.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

#### Header.js

```
import actions from './actions';

@connect(
  // map state to props
  (state, props) => ({
    canNavigate: state.navigation.canNavigate,
  }),
  // map dispatch to props
  {
    goBack: actions.goBack,
    showNavigationAlert: actions.showNavigationAlert,
  }
)
class Header extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      {/* if 'canNavigate' flag is false and user tries to navigate, then show alert */}
      <span
        onClick={this.props.canNavigate ? this.props.goBack : this.props.showNavigationAlert}
      >
          Go back!
      </span>
    );
  }
}
```

#### Content.js

```
import actions from './actions';

@connect(
  // map state to props
  (state, props) => ({
    navigationAlert: state.navigation.navigationAlert,
  }),
  // map dispatch to props
  {
    toggleNavigation: actions.toggleNavigation,
  }
)
class Content extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {/*
            Show modal if 'navigationAlert' flag is true;
            From the modal, if user choose to leave page then call toggleNavigation.
            You may call the corresponding navigation function after this (eg: goBack)
        */}
        {this.props.navigationAlert && <Modal toggleNavigation={this.props.toggleNavigation} />}

        {/* eg: disable navigation when clicked inside the div */}
        <form onClick={this.props.toggleNavigation}>
          Content click!
        </form>
      </div>
    ); 
  }
}
```

#### App.js

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header />
        <Content />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

#### navigationReducer.js

```
const initialState = {
  canNavigate: true,
  navigationAlert: false,
};

export function navigationReducer(state = initialState, action = {}) {
  let newState = {};

  switch (action.type) {
    case TOGGLE_NAVIGATION:
      return { ...state, canNavigate: !state.canNavigate };

    case TOGGLE_NAVIGATION_ALERT:
      return { ...state, navigationAlert: !state.navigationAlert };

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

#### actions.js

```
export function toggleNavigation(gdsSession) {
  return { type: TOGGLE_NAVIGATION };
}

export function toggleNavigationAlert(gdsSession) {
  return { type: TOGGLE_NAVIGATION_ALERT };
}

// ... other actions
```

and render into DOM.

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

Comment: Yes this is a workaround, but it still doesn't give me the amount of control I want over the header-buttons from my context component. Ideally I would like to optionally override the header's buttons if desired by the content component.

Comment: This is how we usually implement communication between components via global store. But I am still unclear about the statement "optionally control navigation". Can you give a better use case? What I attempted here is to solve the use case that you gave in the question.